# Bootstrap - How do i make the body wrap around the jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The body height on my login page is set to 100% but when the page is viewed in landscape mode on mobile, the jumbotron overflows from the body at the bottom. Why isn't the body occupying the full height of the screen on landscape? How can I fix this? Plus, I need to center the jumbotron in such a manner that the whole jumbotron is visible even on landscape mode. Any help with that too would be much appreciated.

Here's an image of the problem:
[image: The body does not wrap the jumbotron]

**EDIT: SOLVED** As @Markus Kottländer pointed out, I set the min-height of the body in px to ensure it covers the jumbotron always and (as pointed out by @cvrebert in the comments) I used the vh unit to eliminate the need to set a fixed height and thus avoid the scrollbar when unnecessary. This solved the problem.

Comment: Use the [`vh` CSS unit](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) instead of `height: 100%`?

Answer (score 2):

Set the `min-height` to 100% instead of `height`. Your `BodyWrapper` has a fixed height of 100%, with min-height it will also adjust to more than 100%.

Comment: Actually, as you suggested, I set the min-height of the body in px to ensure it covers the jumbotron always and used the vh unit to eliminate the need to set a fixed height and thus avoid the scrollbar when unnecessary. This solved the problem. Thank you and thanks to @cvrebert for pointing out that I can use vh.